# Scaling a view hides the content

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, view

[image: This] is the view which I have designed with the following code of xml

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                 ....
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="84dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/meal_ln"
                        android:background="@drawable/meal_img_bg_ac"
                        app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/meal_ln"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lunch"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/priTxtLight"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                        android:fontFamily="casual"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                 ....
                </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

My target is to design [image: this view]. And for this I added

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:scaleX="1.6"
                    android:scaleY="1.6"
                    >
```

in the second one which result in view cut as [image: this view]

How can I correct this issue?

I want to scale the middle view bigger than other two. In this both the image and text should be visible and should be bigger.

Problem which I found is: Linear layout is hiding the content of overflowing relative layout.

Comment: Try with scale 1.2 or maximum 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LinearLayout` with orientation `vertical` instead of `RelativeLayout`

```js
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                 ....
                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="84dp"
                        android:layout_height="84dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/meal_ln"
                        android:background="@drawable/meal_img_bg_ac"
                        app:layout_aspectRatio="100%"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/meal_ln"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Lunch"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/priTxtLight"
                        android:paddingTop="4dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                        android:fontFamily="casual"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                 ....
                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: its still hiding content

Comment: Where are you using scaleX and scaleY ?